# javascript function overridden by post back in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a nested grid view which has been implemented by following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
```

and following way of gridview definition:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

For getting the data for child gridview I need the text of selected row in parent gridview, on server side. And even further processing requires text data of selected rows of both the gridviews. For this I tried to get the text in `OnSelectedIndexChanged` function BUT that being a post back request, collapses the expanded row(i.e. resets it).

Is there a solution which does not require javascript and creates the nested gridview directly from the server side? Or any other solution in which I can get the data server side but still keep the expanded row as expanded only.

Comment: You can try to store ids or text of expandedparentgrid in hiddenfield and manually set them expanded after post back.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your nested `Gridview` control inside an update panel to prevent the whole page post-back on `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
        DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: no, not working, probably because the outer grid has to be in update panel.

Comment: Where do you place the control for `OnSelectedIndexChanged` ?

Comment: that is on each gridview(outer + inner) as I need text on server from both of them.